# How to select only specific fields from joined entity in Typeorm - without QueryBuilder

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to get all records from my user entity, and I want to filter result in query to show only specific values. I'm using typorm^0.2.25. Is there anyway to achieve the result without using query builder? I couldn't find anything in their documentation for this specific scenario.

Entities that I have:

User:

```
import { Account } from "./Account";


@Entity()
@Unique(["email"])
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @ManyToOne(() => Status, (status) => status.players)
  status: Status;

  @OneToMany(() => Account, (account) => account.player)
  accounts: Account[];

}
```

Status:

```
import { User } from "./User";

@Entity()
export class Status {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.status, { nullable: true })
  users?: User[];
}
```

Account:

```
import { User } from "./User";
import { Currency } from "./Currency";

@Entity()
export class Account {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column("numeric", {
    scale: 2,
    precision: 7,
    transformer: new ColumnNumericTransformer(),
    default: 0,
  })
  balance: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.accounts, {
    nullable: true,
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Currency, (currency) => currency.accounts)
  currency: Currency;

}
```

Currency:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  Generated,
  OneToMany,
} from "typeorm";
import { Account } from "./Account";

@Entity()
export class Currency {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  symbol: string;

  @Column()
  code: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Account, (account) => account.currency, { nullable: true })
  accounts?: Account[];
}
```

Method that I use to get all:

```
const userRepository: Repository<User> = getRepository(User);
const users = await userRepository.find({
      order: {
        createdAt: "DESC"
      },
      join: {
        alias: "user",
        leftJoinAndSelect: {
          accounts: "user.accounts",
          accountCurrency: "accounts.currency",
          status: "user.status",
        },
      },
    });
```

I recieve something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "password": "sha1$ac984093$1$a3ba245822a679c52e6be292142244aa16a196ad",
    "firstName": "Matt",
    "lastName": "Marvin",
    "email": "bacoxoy714@shzsedu.com",
    "createdAt": "2021-04-06T12:36:46.830Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-04-06T12:37:04.941Z",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "balance": 0,
        "currency": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Euro",
          "symbol": "€",
          "code": "EUR"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "currency": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Euro",
          "symbol": "€",
          "code": "EUR"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "balance": 0,
        "currency": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Euro",
          "symbol": "€",
          "code": "EUR"
        }
      }
    ],
    "status": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "active"
    }
  }
]
```

What I want to receive is:

```
[
    {
      "firstName": "Matt",
      "lastName": "Marvin",
      "email": "bacoxoy714@shzsedu.com",
      "createdAt": "2021-04-06T12:36:46.830Z",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "balance": 0,
          "currency": {
            "code": "EUR"
          }
        },
        {
          "balance": 0,
          "currency": {
            "code": "EUR"
          }
        },
        {
          "balance": 0,
          "currency": {
            "code": "EUR"
          }
        }
      ],
      "status": {
        "name": "active"
      }
    }
]
```